# While Loop not repeating

Tags: java, while-loop

I have having a hard time getting this while loop to execute. I tried it without resetting the scanner first, and it would loop but throw the second line immediatly with the first line, so It was suggested to add the scanner reset lines. Now the loop does not repeat at all....any suggestions? I am looking at the first while loop in the main program, that is supposed to repeat the entire program until "quit" is entered into the empName field. Not the smaller while loops nested in the middle.

```
 Scanner input;
   empName = " ";
   while (!empName.equals("quit"))
   {
     input = new Scanner (System.in);
     System.out.print( "Enter employee name or enter 'quit' when finished. " );
     empName = myScanner.nextLine();
     hourlyRate = -1;
     while (hourlyRate <= 0)
     {
       System.out.print( "What is their hourly rate? $");
       hourlyRate = myScanner.nextDouble();
       if (hourlyRate <= 0)
       {
           System.out.println( "Value is not valid, please enter an amount above zero.");
       }
     }
     totHours = -1;
     while (totHours <= 0)
     {
         System.out.print( "How many hours did they work? ");
         totHours = myScanner.nextDouble();
         if (totHours <= 0)
         {
            System.out.println( "Value is not valid, please enter an amount above zero.");
         }
     }
     if (totHours > 40.00)//Calculate Pay and Taxes if OT
     {
        otHours = totHours - 40;
        regHours = totHours - otHours;
        otPay = (1.5 * hourlyRate) * otHours;
        regPay = hourlyRate * regHours;
        grossPay = regPay + otPay;
        taxes = grossPay * .13;
        netPay = grossPay - taxes;
//Display OT information
        System.out.print( "Employee name: ");
        System.out.println(empName);
        System.out.print( "Hourly Rate: ");
        System.out.println(money.format(hourlyRate));
        System.out.print( "Regular Hours Worked: ");
        System.out.println(regHours);
        System.out.print( "OT Hours Worked: ");
        System.out.println(otHours);
        System.out.print( "Total Hours Worked: ");
        System.out.println(totHours);
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.print( "Regular Pay = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(regPay));
        System.out.print( "Overtime Pay = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(otPay));
        System.out.print( "Gross Pay = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(grossPay));
        System.out.print( "Federal Taxes = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(taxes));
        System.out.println( "   ");
        System.out.print( "Net Pay = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(netPay));
     }
     else //Calculate No OT Pay and Taxes
     {
        grossPay = hourlyRate * totHours;
        taxes = .13 * grossPay;
        netPay = grossPay - taxes;
//Display No OT Information
        System.out.print( "Employee name: ");
        System.out.println(empName);
        System.out.print( "Hourly Rate: ");
        System.out.println(money.format(hourlyRate));
        System.out.print( "Hours Worked: ");
        System.out.println(totHours);
        System.out.println( "   ");
        System.out.print( "Gross Pay = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(grossPay));
        System.out.print( "Federal Taxes = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(taxes));
        System.out.println( "   ");
        System.out.print( "Net Pay = ");
        System.out.println(money.format(netPay));
        System.out.println( "   ");
     }
   String clearBuffer = input.nextLine();
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: which one? please only post relevant code. there are 3 `while`s in there.

Comment: I would make some test output to find out why the loop condition fails (or use a debugger)

Comment: Please cut down the code to only what's relevant. I suspect that in doing so, you'll find the problem - and if not, you should end up with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem... I'd expect it to be no more than 20 lines.

Comment: What is the `myScanner` variable? Provide us not cut source

Comment: A few things you can do: - cut your code (as others said); - dump the value of emp_name right before it gets evaluated in the while loop (consider while(flag==1) as the actual loop statement, print the value as the first statement, then add a if() flag = 0; this way you have a chance to examine your values in the loop.

Comment: I think you should move `input = new Scanner (System.in);` out of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the third line of the following block (at the point where you read the employee name) is the way to fix this with the fewest changes to your code.

```
 System.out.print( "Enter employee name or enter 'quit' when finished. " );
 empName = myScanner.nextLine();
 if(empName.equals("quit")) break;
```